# Chrome extension content scripts not injected when navigating

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing google chrome extension and encountered following problem. Content scripts are not being injected when navigating on YouTube. However, when the page is reloaded or opened in a new tab, they work. It seems to work on any web site except Google's ones. No errors in console. Tried different "run_at" options with no luck.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Test",
    "content_scripts": [
                        {
                            "js": [
                                   "contentScripts.js"
                                   ],
                            "matches": [ "*://*.youtube.com/watch*"],
                            "run_at": "document_start"
                        }
                        ],
    "permissions": [
                    "*://*.youtube.com/watch*"
                    ]
}
```

**contentScripts.js**

```
alert("TEST");
```

Comment: It's not a navigation, it's actually a history state change.